# Android: how to implement irregular buttons next to each other?

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, shapes

I want to implement an interface with some irregular buttons, like this:

[image]

Is this possible in Android with regular button componentes, or do I need to use another approach (like using images and detect clicked areas)?

Answer (score 0):

I pretty sure that there is no standard way of dealing with such problem.

I guess the best approach would be to override onTouch in Button and detect clicked area manually. If the shape is really complex, or bitmap based, you can try to draw some kind of mask and then simply getPixel from your button canvas. If the pixel is (for example) black, then the button was clicked.

Also see: [Can handle events on irregular shapes on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607768/can-handle-events-on-irregular-shapes-on-android)