# Detecting touch events on shapes

Tags: android, android-canvas

I've got this graph-like circle that is divided in several "portions". I draw these using drawArc on a canvas.

```
canvas.drawArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle, true, fillPaint);
```

I would like to make these arcs clickeable so I can trigger events when the user taps them. So I decided to override onTouchEvent, then for ACTION_DOWN go through all my portions and check if the touch position lies within them.

I tried [this code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607768/can-handle-events-on-irregular-shapes-on-android) which is answering to a similar question, but I am getting strange angle values (i.e. negative values for top right quadrant, values between 180-270 in the rest of them).

```
public boolean isInArea(float x, float y){
        int deltaX = (int) (x - oval.centerX());
        int deltaY = (int) (y - oval.centerY());

        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2)) > mRectShape.width()/2) {
            return false;
        }

     // offset for radiant, depending on quadrant
        double offset = 0;
        if (deltaX > 0 && deltaY < 0) {
            // top right -> nothing to do
        } else if (deltaX > 0 && deltaY > 0) {
            // bottom right -> add 90 degrees
            offset = Math.PI/2;
        } else if (deltaX < 0 && deltaY > 0) {
            // bottom left -> add 180 degrees
            offset = Math.PI;
        } else if (deltaX < 0 && deltaY < 0) {
            // top left -> add 270 degrees
            offset = Math.PI * 3/2;
        }

        //now calculate angle
        double angle = Math.asin(deltaY / deltaX);
        double total = angle + offset;
        double totalDeg = total * 180 / Math.PI;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "angle :" + totalDeg);

        if(totalDeg > mStartAngle && totalDeg < mSweepAngle){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I also tried without setting the offsets nand then I get negative values for top quadrants, and positive values between 0 and 180 in the bottom ones.

Also tried using atan2 like this:

```
angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, -deltaX);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: are arcs views? Or are you drawing it on a canvas? Without code it is impossible to help you

Comment: (in case it wasn't clear, I am drawing it on a canvas)